# Windows Phone 7 files transfer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to understand how to transfer files in Windows Phone 7 app with TCP. 
Maybe, there're a lot of questions like this, but it's my first experience in this aspect. 
So, researching this theme, I read that everything is based on Sockets. 
It'll be great if you show me simple example of using this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202858(v=vs.92).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202959(v=vs.92).aspx